# a regex question

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string in PHP:

```
<p> [#form id=1]</p>
```

What is the pattern for getting it? I tried this:

```
/\<p\>\s\[\#.+?.\]\s\<\/p\>/
```

But it does not work. Any idea?

Comment: To match that chunk, to match the id attribute, to match that specific pattern or arbitrary chars within `p` tags?

Comment: Ahem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Is it possible to use a parser instead? You shouldn't really use regex to match html: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/parsing-beyond-regex.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/\<p\>\s*\[\#.+?.\]\s*\<\/p\>/
```

You don't have space after ] , but regexp test for it

Answer (score 2):

In the string there is nothing between `]` and `<`

```
<p> [#form id=1]</p>
               ^^
```

But in your regex you've a `\s` (one whitespace character) between `]` and `<`. Either drop the `\s` if you are sure there will be nothing between or change it to `\s*` if there can be any number of whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a space after the `]` sign,

Have a try with :

```
~<p> \[#.+\]</p>~
```